# ML technique recommendations where each feature has multiple properties and the number of features per observation varies

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, feature-engineering

Here is an abstracted version of the problem I am facing.

I wish to predict the true value of a variable from multiple noisy predictions as to its value. There are three complicating factors:

For each observation, I receive multiple noisy predictions from different sources. The sources may each provide valuable information, but are likely to differ in their accuracy (I'm using accuracy in its common sense rather than as a technical term here).

Each prediction is timestamped, with later predictions tending to be more accurate than earlier ones. The function which defines the relationship between time and accuracy is strictly increasing but otherwise unknown (e.g. it may be discontinuous, the order rather than the amount of time elapsed may be the only thing that matters).

The number of predictions obtained from any given source is not constant across observations (and the number of predictions for any given observation varies from source to source).

Just to provide a very rough illustration:

**obs 1:**

y = 2.5,

x[t=10,s=1] = 2.6,

x[t=7,s=3] = 2.2,

x[t=4,s=1] = 2.3,

x[t=3,s=3] = 3.1

**obs 2:**

y = 4.2,

x[t=8,s=3] = 4.5,

x[t=3,s=1] = 3.7,

x[t=2,s=1] = 3.8

x[t=1,s=2] = 3.8
etc

So what do I do guys? I'm having real trouble seeing how to translate this data into a table of features. The main problem I can see is that the source, timestamp, and value for each observation of x seem to be inseparable and thus ought to be coded as a single feature. But this appears to be impossible.

I suppose modelling each source separately and ensembling the models would be easier, but it doesn't seem ideal. For instance, even if source 1 is generally more accurate, it shouldn't be weighted as highly if its predictions are on average earlier for a given observation.

I imagine that some kind of neural network would be best at aggregating these data in such a way as to take advantage of all the potential non-linearities, but I'm struggling to work out would the best algorithm would be and how to engineer features for it.

Comment: Is each sensor specific to each output, or does each sensor measure each output? When you say accuracy is non-decreasing: is that absolute or in expectation? If absolute then you could ignore all but the latest. Is the probability of observing a measurement independent of the value measured? Or do measurements happen more frequently based on the value of y?

Comment: Output is uni-dimensional. That is, for each observation, we have some number of sources each making some number of measurements as to a single output value. The sources are constant across observations (we can make the assumption that each source makes at least one prediction of each output - I'll edit the example).

Accuracy is increasing in expectation, by which I mean that the variance of the white noise in each prediction is falling (but there could still be valuable information in those previous observations).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the x samples:

- Treat the indexes of x (time and source) and its values as separate columns (e.g. x now has examples of 3 fields like (t,s_t,x_t)).
- Discretize your timestamps (e.g. granularity of 1 sec ou 1 min).
- At the instants t that don't have data, fill the fields with the mean of the other examples. A worse but easier workaround is filling with dummy values (e.g. zero).

For y:

- Use LSTM to map from x but take only the last output to compute the result (e.g. add a regression layer at the end)
  OR
- Use LSTM and aggregate all outputs (e.g. with mean and variance) and do regression with the result (e.g. with regression layer at the end)

Comment: Thank you - I will try this. One question, I am concerned that accuracy does not vary with time in a smooth manner. For instance, it might be a step function. That is, the sensor may provide an update when the sensor receives enough additional information to refine the prediction. In that case the time elapsed is irrelevant. Do you think I could model this by encoding a one-hot vector of features of dim(T*S) with a value of one if sensor s provided an update at t (alongside the vector of values with mean used for missing data)? Or by some other means?

Comment: By "one-hot vector of features of dim(T*S)" you mean represent your time series as one big vector?

Comment: Anyway I think you can put that as input feature as well. Instead of using mean for missing data you can also interpolate neighboring values. And you can also represent the sources as one-hot encoding instead symbol.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. LSTM definitely looks interesting so I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide much detail in your question, so the answer is likewise somewhat vague. What is clear is that you have a panel data structure. Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data) for how this is usually formatted. Given that your observations are unequally spaced, you will have many missing data points. There are two solutions to this:

1. Reduce missing values by downsampling the observed data, which obviously results in information loss.
2. Create new data that resembles the observed data with a (multiple) imputation process. This does not result in information loss, but may seriously bias the results. How serious depends on many factors.

But in the example that you describe, there may be another interesting solution. If the sensors all measure the same thing, but with differing accuracy, then they can represented as measurements of a single sensor with a varying (but known) accuracy. This collapses one dimension of the panel, thus reducing the amount of missing data. But no information needs to be lost because the accuracy of the different sensors can be encoded as sampling weights.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Just to be clear, the approach would be to estimate the relative accuracy of each sensor - for instance, by calculating the mean squared error of the latest (most accurate) prediction for each sensor - and then weighting all of each sensor's predictions accordingly? Am I right in thinking that this makes assumption that the function that describes the increase in a sensor's accuracy over time is the same for each sensor?

Comment: Note that each observation has an individual sample weight, so there is no other restriction than that they sum to one over the entire sample. The problem is how to obtain a set of reasonable sample weights. Ideally, one would know the relative accuracy of each sensor at each point in time, but this is likely unavailable. If sensor accuracy does not change over time, one could estimate the *average* relative accuracy of each of the sensors - and assign sample weights that remain constant over time. But I would not know how to assign sample weights if sensor accuracy *does* change over time.

Comment: How about:

- fit separate models for each sensor to derive separate functions for the variation of accuracy over time.

- in the full dataset, weight each prediction at each time accordingly, allowing you to treat each sensor the same way

- refit using the same technique as in the first stage.

The question then is what technique to use? LSTM (as mentioned by the other commenter) looks like it could be promising (but I have no experience with neural nets). But I don't know if there's something better for unevenly-space time series data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a one-trick pony lately, but this seems like a perfect case for Bayesian methods. You need incremental information, and the fact that the observations are noisy further supports the case for them.

Your goal would be to get $p(Y|S,P,X, [T])$, where the parameters are:

$S$ - Source

$P$ - Precision (i.e. reliability of the source)

$X$ - Value measured by the Source.

$T$ - Time (optional, and will complicate matters)

For multiple sources, you can then combine these into the final posterior distribution via the same general procedure.

In particular, if you ignore Time and your sources are some physical measurements (or are otherwise very macro-scale), it should be safe to model them all as Gaussians. This would let you plug in the numbers to an already established equations in a fairly straightforward fashion.

To spare some virtual trees, and since I don't know if you know the source precision or not, you can find them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution).

Comment: Thanks for your comment - the issue is that I have reason to believe that time is the most important feature when it comes to accuracy. That is, later values carry much more information than earlier values, irrespective of the source (so you'd rather use the latest value from a single source than aggregate all values from multiple sources). In addition, the precision of the sources is unknown Would there be a way to incorporate this into a Bayesian methodology? Maybe by starting with the average latest signal as the mean of a Gaussian for a prior? Not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: You can account for time, I thought you meant it increases the precision - but you just have a preference for fresher data, so it's just another variable that can be modelled as independently influencing the prediction. I would wrangle it to 'offset from now into the past' and make it exponential. The precision being totally unknown can be handled; you can either just straight up assume it arbitrarily for each source, model it as a Gamma, or establish it empirically if you can.

Comment: Thanks - can you point me to any sources on practical model fitting using Bayesian methods? I am familiar with it on a theoretical/mathematical level (conjugate priors, data augmentation, max a posteriori) but don't know where to start with putting it into practice.

Comment: Have you had a look at Bayesian Methods for Hackers? It's available as, of all things, a Git repo, for free. You can find it at: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers